# dotnet application refusing to serve .dll files in wwwroot needed by blazor webassembly

Tags: blazor, file-not-found

My dotnet application is refusing to serve `.dll` files in wwwroot application needed by Blazor web assembly. Dotnet can see the files so there is no permission issue. I think probably there is a security setting in dotnet that is preventing it from statically serving the `.dll` files

I even wrote this code to verify the `.dll` files are actually copied over by Docker and I see them:

```
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Join("wwwroot", "_framework")))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }
```

Console log:

```
sudo docker run -p 8080:80 -it --rm amir734jj/symmetric-crypto-chatroom
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Security.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_no_CJK.dat
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_EFIGS.dat.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/NSec.Cryptography.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.1.pm4grxxe0f.js.gz
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.1.pm4grxxe0f.js
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.wasm.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Blazor.Extensions.Logging.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Requests.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.IO.Pipelines.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
wwwroot/_framework/UI.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Specialized.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Blazored.SessionStorage.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Core.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/netstandard.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Json.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.boot.json
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Requests.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.4.im9dizu1ff.js
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Queryable.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.1.pm4grxxe0f.js.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Channels.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Models.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Http.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Thread.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll   // <---------- HERE, DLL is there
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Mail.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Primitives.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.wasm.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.Bootstrap.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Mail.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_EFIGS.dat
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_CJK.dat
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll
wwwroot/_framework/netstandard.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
wwwroot/_framework/icudt.dat.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Blazored.SessionStorage.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Channels.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Blazor.Extensions.Logging.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.timezones.blat.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.timezones.blat
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Queryable.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Http.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/BlazorDownloadFile.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Claims.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.CoreLib.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/netstandard.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Specialized.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/UI.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.IO.Pipelines.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Expressions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Expressions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Primitives.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_no_CJK.dat.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Console.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Console.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.Uri.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Mail.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_EFIGS.dat.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
wwwroot/_framework/BlazorDownloadFile.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.Bootstrap.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Memory.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Blazored.SessionStorage.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.Abstractions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Client.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Blazor.Extensions.Logging.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Models.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.timezones.blat.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Specialized.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/NSec.Cryptography.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Core.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_CJK.dat.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.Json.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Channels.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Expressions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Memory.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.wasm
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Claims.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Http.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.Bootstrap.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.dll
wwwroot/_framework/UI.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/icudt.dat.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.ObjectModel.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Security.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.IO.Pipelines.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Json.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.Queryable.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Linq.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client.Core.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.Common.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.ObjectModel.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Models.pdb.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
wwwroot/_framework/UI.pdb.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Json.dll
wwwroot/_framework/NSec.Cryptography.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.ObjectModel.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.4.im9dizu1ff.js.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Features.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Thread.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.boot.json.gz
wwwroot/_framework/icudt.dat
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_no_CJK.dat.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Common.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Console.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Memory.dll
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Cryptography.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Security.Claims.dll
wwwroot/_framework/BlazorDownloadFile.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.CoreLib.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Models.dll
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.boot.json.br
wwwroot/_framework/dotnet.7.0.4.im9dizu1ff.js.gz
wwwroot/_framework/BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll
wwwroot/_framework/icudt_CJK.dat.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Threading.Thread.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.Uri.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Core.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Primitives.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.CoreLib.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Security.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.Net.Requests.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Private.Uri.dll
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Havit.Blazor.Components.Web.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll.gz
wwwroot/_framework/System.ComponentModel.dll.br
wwwroot/_framework/Microsoft.JSInterop.dll.br
```

Error:

[image]

[image]

Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    private static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Error))
            .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
            {
                logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
                logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
            }).Build();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", true)
            .AddJsonFile("secureHeaderSettings.json", true, true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        _configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Join("wwwroot", "_framework")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => builder
            .WithOrigins(_configuration.GetSection("TrustedSpaUrls").Get<string[]>())
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowCredentials()));

        services.AddOptions();

        services.AddLogging();

        services.AddRouting();
        
        services.AddSignalR(c =>
        {
            c.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1024; // 50 mega-bytes
            c.StreamBufferCapacity = 50;
            c.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });

        services.AddSingleton<ILiteDatabase>(new LiteDatabase("db.litedb"));
        services.AddSingleton<PlaybackLogic>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles()
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseRouting()
            .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat");
            });
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0-alpine AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY . .

# NuGet restore
RUN dotnet restore

WORKDIR "/app/API"

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

WORKDIR "/app/UI"

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

RUN cp -rpf /app/UI/out/wwwroot /app/API/out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env "/app/API/out" .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

[Repository](https://github.com/amir734jj/symmetric-crypto-chat-room/tree/08caa83fbcc50516de42ff660ea65ed8191b4c63)

Comment: Found the solution. The solution is this: `.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
            })`

Comment: Write a (more detailed) answer please, not a comment

Comment: @AD7six it was a 1 in million guesses after 3 hours of trying to fix it that seem to fix the problem. I don't have more details on why it worked.

Comment: K, well - That’s not how stack overflow works. I’m sure you can at least put that code block in a readable form in an answer :). You can also remove irrelevant details from the question with that new insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The reason dotnet was refusing to serve the `.dll` files needed in Blazor was that they have an unknown `ContentType`. [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.staticfileoptions.serveunknownfiletypes?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Replacing this:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles()
.UseStaticFiles()
.UseRouting()
.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });
```

With this:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles()
.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
})
.UseRouting()
.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapHub<MessageHub>("/chat"); });
```

Fixed the problem